# Divergence of Summation

Tags: real-analysis

I'm given the following:$\sum \frac{n!}{e^{n^2}}$. I did the ratio test and ended up with $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n+1}{e^{2n+1}}$. I'm fairly certain that this converges to zero but I'm not sure how to prove this rigorously. I think it might have something to do with Monotone Convergence Theorem/Order Limit Theorem, but I'm welcome to any proofs.

Comment: L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Remember that "exponentials beat powers"

Answer (score 1):

Squeeze theorem. You know that $\mathrm e >2$, so, 
$$
\mathrm e^{2n+1} > 2^{2n+1} > 2^n = (1+1)^n = \sum_0^n \binom n k > \binom n 2 = \frac {n(n-1)}2, 
$$
and
$$
\frac {n+1}{n(n-1)/2} = 2\cdot \frac {n^{-2} + n^{-1}}{1 - n^{-1}} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty}  0,
$$
hence the limit is $0$ by squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{2n+1} =$

$1 +(2n+1)+(2n+1)^2/2! .+..\gt$

$ (2n+1)^2/2!$.

$\left |\dfrac{n+1}{e^{2n+1}}\right | \lt \dfrac {2(2n+1)}{(2n+1)^2} =$

$\dfrac{2}{2n+1} \lt  \dfrac{2}{2n} = \dfrac{1}{n}.$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{e^{2n+1}}.$$
Applying the ratio test on this series, we obtain
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{n+2}{e^{2n+3}} \div \frac{n+1}{e^{2n+1}}\right| = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n+2}{e^2(n+1)} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1+\frac{2}{n}}{e^2\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)} = \frac{1}{e^2} < 1.$$
Hence, the above series converges. By the divergence test,
$$\frac{n+1}{e^{2n+1}} \to 0.$$